# how to format time in java?

Tags: java, time, format

How to format time in libgdx(java)?

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(TimeUtils.timeSinceMillis(startTime));
```

I want to format like this:

min:sec:mil

00:00:00 or 00:00:000

Comment: See the DateTimeFormater: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this;

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");
    System.out.println(sDate.format(startTime));
```

Output is;

```
05:42.331
```

If you want also with hour;

```
Format sDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Comment: Don't want to be that guy when it comes to dates in Java, but also be aware of the JodaTime library for a far easier way to work with dates DateTime myDate = 
DateTime.now().toString("HH:mm:ss.SSS");